# Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST

Tags: spring, websphere, classloader

I am getting this exception while a JSON call is made from ui

```
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.canSerialize(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference;)Z (loaded from file:/C:/lib/lib/commonutils.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.ExtJarClassLoader@7a68e094[server:0]
   Local ClassPath: C:\lib;C:\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\lib\cfusion.jar;C:\lib\CfusionPostalone.jar;C:\lib\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\lib\CIMConfig.jar;C:\lib\classmate-0.8.0.jar;C:\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\lib\commons-lang-2.5.jar;C:\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\lib\commonutils.jar;C:\lib\ConcurrenceCommon.jar;C:\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:\lib\httpcache4j-api-3.2.jar;C:\lib\httpcache4j-core-3.2.jar;C:\lib\httpcache4j-storage-api-3.2.jar;C:\lib\httpclient-4.2.3.jar;C:\lib\httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar;C:\lib\httpcore-4.2.2.jar;C:\lib\itext-1.4.6.jar;C:\lib\jackson-all-1.9.11.jar;C:\lib\jackson-core-2.7.5.jar;C:\lib\jersey-apache-client-1.17.jar;C:\lib\jersey-apache-client4-1.17.1.jar;C:\lib\jersey-bundle-1.17.jar;C:\lib\jersey-cache-client-0.2.2.jar;C:\lib\joda-time-2.2-javadoc.jar;C:\lib\joda-time-2.2-sources.jar;C:\lib\joda-time-2.2.jar;C:\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\lib\oauth-client-1.9-ea04.jar;C:\lib\oauth-signature-1.9-ea04.jar;C:\lib\ojdbc6.jar;C:\lib\p1-common-util.jar;C:\lib\poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar;C:\lib\POWS-Client.jar;C:\lib\POWS-Domain.jar;C:\lib\SecureWeb.jar;C:\lib\SharedSession.jar;C:\lib\ujac.jar;C:\lib\usps4cb.jar;C:\lib\lib\j2ee.jar;C:\lib\lib\commonutils.jar
   Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@4e8810bb
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST) called from class org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter (loaded from file:/C:/project/R45.3.0_EAR/lib/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@8881b946[app:R45.3.0_EAR]
   Local ClassPath: C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\activation.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\admin-ws_proxy.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-beanutils.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-collections-3.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-lang-2.5.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-logging-1.1.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commons-validator-1.3.1.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\commonutils.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\cxf-2.2.10.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\displaytag-1.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\itext-1.4.8.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\j2ee.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jackson-core-2.8.7.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jaxb-api-2.1.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jettison-1.0.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jsr311-api-1.0.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\jstl-1.2.1.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\mybatis-3.2.2.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\mybatis-spring-1.2.0.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\pager-taglib.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\PostalOneScaleReader.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\POWS-Client.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\POWS-Domain.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\quartz-all-1.6.5.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-context-support-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-instrument-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-oxm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-security-taglibs-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\xbean-2.4.0.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\xmlbeans-qname.jar;C:\project\R45.3.0_EAR\lib\xstream-1.3.jar
   Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ExtJarClassLoader@7a68e094[PF][server:0]
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST).
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:131 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at com.usps.postalone.mei.web.support.PbvfsSecurityFilter.doFilter(PbvfsSecurityFilter.java:97)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:133 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:133 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:133 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:133 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
[5/24/17 14:38:41:133 EDT] 00000257 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
```

these are my jars

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/activation.jar
                                                lib/adminws-client.jar
                                                lib/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
                                                lib/commons-beanutils.jar
                                                lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
                                                lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar
                                                lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
                                                lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
                                                lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar
                                                lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar
                                                lib/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
                                                lib/commonutils.jar
                                                lib/cxf-2.2.10.jar
                                                lib/displaytag-1.2.jar
                                                lib/displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
                                                lib/displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar
                                                lib/itext-1.4.8.jar
                                                lib/j2ee.jar
                                lib/jackson-core-2.8.7
                                                lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2
                                                lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2
                                                lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar
                                                lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
                                                lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar
                                                lib/jettison-1.0.jar
                                                lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar
                                                lib/jsr311-api-1.0.jar
                                                lib/jstl-1.2.1.jar
                                                lib/junit-4.8.2.jar
                                                lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar
                                                lib/mybatis-3.2.2.jar
                                                lib/mybatis-spring-1.2.0.jar
                                                lib/pager-taglib.jar
                                                lib/quartz-all-1.6.5.jar
                                                lib/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-context-support-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-instrument-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-jms-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-oxm-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-security-taglibs-4.2.1.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.6.RELEASE
                                                lib/xbean-2.4.0.jar
                                                lib/xmlbeans-qname.jar
                                                lib/xstream-1.3.jar
                                lib/gson-2.2.4.jar
            "/>
```

any suggestions pls. server level parent first is disabled. I am looking to fix locally not server level.

Comment: I think Your Spring and Jackson versions are not compatible. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.canSerialize. Could you add your maven pom or gradle build file here.

Comment: @PraneethRamesh.. have added my jars from build.xml

Comment: You have Spring 4 and Jackson version 1.X.X is not compatible with that. Try using com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8 Jackson jars

Comment: @Geek Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Spring in your application is not compatible with the version of Jackson in your shared library.  The shared library is associated with a server-level shared library class loader, and as such, the shared library's copy of Jackson is loaded in preference to the copy in your application.  Assuming the Jackson in your EAR/lib is the version you actually want, you should be able to simply remove it from the shared library and resolve the problem.

Comment: I removed jackson-core-2.7.5, jackson-all-1.9.11 from server lib and use the one in the apaplication EAR. Still getting the same exception.

Comment: I think you might have Jackson classes in another jar - note this line after the method in the NoSuchMethodError: loaded from file:/C:/lib/lib/commonutils.jar